# jQuery - refresh each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a problem with this code :

```
$('#portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
    //Some conditions here to add my class 'thumbnail-view' to some div
   $('#portfolio-list').find('.project').addClass('thumbnail-view');
});

$(".thumbnail-view").each(function(j){
     $(this).click(function(){      
        alert(j);
     });
});
```

Each time I clik on a link in my div id portfolio-filter, I add class thumbnail-view on specific elements.
My each function works fine when I load the page, but it doesn't take into consideration changements thanks to the first function. Should I need to refresh my each function every time I click on a link in #portfolio-filter ? How can I do that ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to recompute the `j` index, a solution is to redo the binding when you add the class.

```
$('#portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
    //Some conditions here to ass my class 'thumbnail-view' to some div
    $('#portfolio-list').find('.project').addClass('thumbnail-view');
    $(".thumbnail-view").off('click').each(function(j){
         $(this).on('click', function(){      
            alert(j);
         });
    });
});
```

Another solution would be to use `on` and to compute the index each time an element is clicked (by iterating over all and comparing with `this`).

Comment: To your 2nd suggestion, you don't need to iterate, just use `index`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I've seen your answer. If it works (I'm not really used to that function whose documentation is too elusive and I'm too lazy to test) then it's the best one. I'll just wait for confirmation and then upvote it ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. dystroy, what you suggest works fine.
I didn't know the existance of off()

Comment: @dystroy Yeah, I agree `index` can be confusing.  Especially since it functions differently based on how it is called.  In this case it does work rather nicely.  http://jsfiddle.net/u7m87/  When called on a collection and passing a dom element it gives the index of the element within the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation and then use [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) in place of your `j`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".thumbnail-view", function() {
    alert($(".thumbnail-view").index(this));
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u7m87/)

Comment: `$(document)` -> `$('#portfolio-list')`

Comment: @KevinB Yes, potentially, assuming that element is not itself dynamic in any way.  I had to run to a meeting or I would have included my usual disclaimer.  `document` should be replaced by the nearest common static ancestor element.  `document` should be used only as a last resort.

Comment: +1 I tend to slightly prefer this over unbinding and binding again.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".thumbnail-view").on("click",function(){      
       alert(j);
});
```